# Meaning of Xcode Project Bundle settings Install group?

Tags: xcode

We have Build Settings -> Install group/ Alternate Install Group in projects

When I wanna archive my app at home(not in company network) it doesn't work.
I have to delete it to make it work for targets, extensions and Pod bundles.

And it keeps reappearing again and again. I need to connect to my Company VPN to work it out, which currently has issues and It is wasting my time.

I have searched but could not figure out the technicalities of it. 
Someone please let me know what it is.

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution for this?